# How to pass data from an Android Webview to the HTML pages loaded by webview?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, webview

I have an android application that uses a `webview`. I am able to pass the data from `angularjs` controller to the webview using a `Javascript` Interface. But I am unable to pass data back from the webview activity to the angularjs controller. Any help would be appreciated.

(The webview is a normal one and not cordova webview)

Comment: Can we see some relevant code Kumar?

Comment: I am using the following code to invoke a function on my controller which is in a webview:
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

In angular controller:
$scope.sendDetails=function()
  
  {
   Android.callActivity("hi");
   
  };